# Python (2.x) list / sublist selection -1 weirdness

Tags: list, python-2.x, sublist

So I've been playing around with python and noticed something that seems a bit odd. The semantics of `-1` in selecting from a list don't seem to be consistent.

So I have a list of numbers

```
ls = range(1000)
```

The last element of the list if of course `ls[-1]` but if I take a sublist of that so that I get everything from say the midpoint to the end I would do

```
ls[500:-1]
```

but this does not give me a list containing the last element in the list, but instead a list containing everything UP TO the last element. However if I do

```
ls[0:10]
```

I get a list containing also the tenth element (so the selector ought to be inclusive), why then does it not work for `-1`.

I can of course do `ls[500:]` or `ls[500:len(ls)]` (which would be silly). I was just wondering what the deal with -1 was, I realise that I don't need it there.

Comment: Note that this is an older question and some behavior is specific to python2. In python3 the equivalent would be ```ls = list(range(1000))```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

In `list[first:last]`, `last` is not included.

The 10th element is `ls[9]`, in `ls[0:10]` there isn't `ls[10]`.

Answer (score 28):

If you want to get a **sub list including the last element**, you leave blank after colon:

```
>>> ll=range(10)
>>> ll
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> ll[5:]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> ll[:]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 4):

I get consistent behaviour for both instances:

```
>>> ls[0:10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> ls[10:-1]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

Note, though, that tenth element of the list is at index **9**, since the list is 0-indexed. That might be where your hang-up is.

In other words, `[0:10]` doesn't go from index 0-10, it effectively goes from 0 to the tenth element (which gets you indexes 0-9, since the 10 is not inclusive at the end of the slice).

Answer (score 3):

It seems pretty consistent to me; positive indices are also non-inclusive. I think you're doing it wrong. Remembering that range() is also non-inclusive, and that Python arrays are 0-indexed, here's a sample python session to illustrate:

```
>>> d = range(10)
>>> d
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> d[9]
9
>>> d[-1]
9
>>> d[0:9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> d[0:-1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> len(d)
10
```

Answer (score 3):

when slicing an array;

```
ls[y:x]
```

takes the slice from element y upto and but not including x. when you use the negative indexing it is equivalent to using

```
ls[y:-1] == ls[y:len(ls)-1]
```

so it so the slice would be upto the last element, but it wouldn't include it (as per the slice)

Answer (score 3):

-1 isn't special in the sense that the sequence is read backwards, it rather wraps around the ends. Such that **minus one means zero minus one, exclusive** (and, for a positive step value, the sequence is read "from left to right".

so for `i = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, `i[2:-1]` means **from item two to *the beginning minus one (or, 'around to the end')***, which results in `[3]`.
The -1th element, or element **0 backwards 1** is the last `4`, but since it's exclusive, we get 3.

I hope this is somewhat understandable.