# How to acces the next value in for loop

Tags: python

So im trying to get first letters of words(excluding first word, i already solved that) in a sentence.

But it appends spaces to the list.

Would appreciate if you help.

Here's the code:

```
lst = []

for t in (input()):
    if t == " ":
     lst.append(t)

print(*lst, sep="")
```

input1: `asd dfd yjs`

output1: `dy`

Comment: Please provide an input example and the expected output, that isnt very clear what you try to do

Comment: you want to join last char of second word AND first char of third word ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just this:

```
''.join([s[0] for s in input().split()[1:]])
```

**step by step:**

if `input()` returns `asd dfd yjs`

split string ([more](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/)):

```py
input().split() # output: ['asd', 'dfd', 'yjs']
```

sub list ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451157/python-list-sublist-selection-1-weirdness)):

```py
input().split()[1:] # output: ['dfd', 'yjs']
```

one line loop ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545050/python-one-line-for-expression)):

```py
[s[0] for s in ['dfd', 'yjs']] # output: ['d', 'y']
```

sub string ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/how-do-i-get-a-substring-of-a-string-in-python)):

```
s="dfd"
s[0] # output: d
```

concat list of strings ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/how-to-concatenate-items-in-a-list-to-a-single-string)):

```py
''.join(['d', 'y']) # output: dy
```

Answer (score 2):

You may

- split your sentence into words using `x.split()`
- remove the first word, using a slice `[1:]` (from index 1 to the end)
- then keep only the first char of each word and concatenate it to a result string

```
x = input(">")
result = ""
for word in x.split()[1:]:
    result += word[0]
print(result)  # dy
```

---

Using a generator and `str.join` :

```
x = input(">")
result = ''.join(word[0] for word in x.split()[1:])
```

Comment: Sidenote: Best practice for creating a string with a loop is `str.join()`, but for homework, it's not important. `result = ''.join(word[0] for word in x.split()[1:])`

Comment: @wjandrea added it ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're getting spaces because that's what you asked for. Read your code out loud and it will probably make sense:

```py
if t == " ":
    lst.append(t)
```

*If `t` is a space, append it to `lst`*

Seems clear that you will only get spaces.

You want the character *after* `t` to be appended. There's two ways to do that using your `for` loop method: 1) if `t` is a space, append the next character; 2) if the previous character was a space, append `t`. Here's how you might implement #2:

```py
lst = []

prev_char = None
for t in (input()):
    if prev_char == " ":
        lst.append(t)
    prev_char = t

print(*lst, sep="")
```

This will print the first character of ever word except the first word. Initialize `last_char` to a space to include the first word.

Comment: Sweet, but doesn't handle consecutive spaces well.

Comment: @MikeM Could do `if prev_char == " " and t != " ":`

Comment: @MikeM No it doesn't. Just trying to keep things simple to get to the heart of OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.split`:

```
lst = [s[0] for s in input().split()[1:]]
```

Comment: *(excluding first word, i already solved that)*

Comment: didn't seem to be solved in their code.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example:

```py
lst = []
get_next = False

for t in input():
    if t == " ":
        get_next = True
    elif get_next:
        lst.append(t)
        get_next = False

print(*lst, sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot great answers already and this is good case for split.  If you specifically need to collect the next token after a special token in a stream of tokens, here are some other options:

```py
inp = "asd dfd yjs"
lst = []
for a, b in zip(inp[:-1],inp[1:]):
  if a == " ":
     lst.append(b)

print(*lst, sep="")

# With comprehensions - my choice
print("".join([b for a, b in zip(inp[:-1],inp[1:]) if a == " "]))

# With functional approach
from functools import reduce
from operator import add, itemgetter

def has_prior_space(x):
  return x[0] == " "

print(reduce(add, map(itemgetter(1), filter(has_prior_space, zip(inp[:-1], inp[1:])))))
```

In Python 3.10, there will be a new `pairwise` iterator that does this type of "2 at a time" iteration specifically: `zip(inp[:-1],inp[1:])`

Answer (score -2):

Use Array join():

```py
''.join(lst)
```

Comment: Replaced with lst.append(t), but didnt work

Comment: I gave +1, your answer was no problem, the question was incomprehensible